# save array data index wise after Json parsing in swift3

Tags: arrays, json, swift, swift3

I am parsing JSON data stored into array based on index. 
My JSON contains the class name along with sections.

This is my JSON:

> {"errorCode":"0","msg":"Success!!!","classDropdown":[{"schoolName":"Sales School","schoolStatus":"1","standardName":"1","standardId":"13","sectionName":[{"sectionName":"A"},{"sectionName":"B"}]},{"schoolName":"Sales School","schoolStatus":"1","standardName":"2nd","standardId":"14","sectionName":[{"sectionName":"B"}
>   ]}

Code:

```
var standard_data = [String]()
var Section_Data = [String]()

func classdetails()
{
    var errorCode = "1"

    let sataff = "getClassDetails?staffId=" + staffId

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: sataff,
                                      relativeTo: URL(string: url+"/rkapi/api/"))!)

    let session = URLSession.shared

    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let task = session.dataTask(with:request,completionHandler:{(d,response,error)in
        do{
            if let data = d {
                if let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? NSDictionary{
                    errorCode = String(describing: jsonData["errorCode"]!)

                    if errorCode == "0" {
                        if let message_list = jsonData["classDropdown"] as? NSArray {
                            self.standard_data.removeAll()
                            self.Section_Data.removeAll()

                            for i in 0 ..< message_list.count {
                                if let message = message_list[i] as? NSDictionary {
                                    let StandaradName = message["standardName"] as? String

                                   self.standard_data.append(StandaradName!)

                                    let section_values = message["sectionName"] as? NSArray

                                    self.count = (section_values?.count)!

                                    for i in 0..<self.count{
                                        if let classdetails = section_values?[i] as? NSDictionary {
                                            print("count of the classdetails",classdetails.count)

                                            for i in 0..<classdetails.count

                                            {
                                                let sectiondetails = classdetails["sectionName"] as? String

                                                self.Section_Data.append(sectiondetails!)

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                    }
                } else {
                    self.displayAlert("nodata", message: "Data Not Available. Please try again")
                }
            }else {
            }
        } catch let err as NSError {
            print("JSON Error \(err)")
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

After parsing JSON data I am getting this one:

[image]

[image]

When I click class name what are section have the class I want show in to the section popover menu but I tried but it's showing all section.

for example:

```
 class : 1st  ----> section :A-section
                             B-section
```

If select the 1st class it will showing all section, where I did mistake

Comment: As always: The code is very *Objective-C-ish*. Please don't use `NSArray / NSDictionary` in Swift. Use native types `[[String:Any]] / [String:Any]`. Variable names are supposed to start with a lowercase letter and to be *camelCased* rather than *snake_cased*. `URLRequest` is redundant. `GET` is the default so just pass the `URL`. Don't use index based `for` loops,  use fast enumeration (`for message in message_list`). And finally please don't post JSON data as image, post text.

Comment: @vadian thank you for u r replay

Answer (score 0):

It is tough to answer your question since it is not stated very clearly. I *guess* your `standard_data` property is bound to your `CLASS` dropdown and your `Section_Data` property is bound to your `SECTION` dropdown. Given this your observed behaviour is not at all surprising. You only have one `Section_Data` object to which you add all your `sectionName`s. There is simply no way your selection of a `CLASS` is able to influence the rendering of your `SECTION`-dropdown. You would have to react to a selection (by linking an `action`-method) and switch the contents of your `Section` dropdown based on it from another data structure.

This is probably a lot too abstract of an answer, but in order to be more concrete we would have to know more about the specific code you expect to work differently. Please post some more of it and as a friendly piece of advice: first make it run without the added complexity of a `dataTask` before you post it to StackOverflow since it does not appear to have anything to do with either JSON parsing nor arrays as such, your problem is in basic UI-handling.